# 80486 motherboard designing

Tags: motherboard

This was an option for my school project but I did not chose it, however someone could have.

The goal was to develop a motherboard for Intel 80486DX4, using modern parts and design principals, and design it as an embedded processor. No Windows support needed.

Is there any resources on this?

Here is original proposal I prepared in case this being assigned to me:

> This board is designed to be a embedded, legacy-free platform. Besides the main processor Intel 80486DX4, 32KB SRAM and 4GB of onboard DRAM with an FPGA as DRAM controller as well as DMA controller, a secondary MMU implemented with another FPGA that have 48 address bits, there is also an ATSAM3X8E microcontroller onboard acting as a system controller as well as a combined USB, SPI, I2C and Ethernet interface, 256MB of NOR Flash, a DS3231 real-time clock and a Parallax Propeller as GPU. Some extra FPGAs are used to provide a SATA interface. The system bus is a modified ISA bus with 32 bit address and data lines. No A20 gating is used, this processor runs exclusively in 32-bit mode
>
> Upon boot, the last 32KB of the NOR Flash is mapped at 0x8000 and the 32KB SRAM mapped at 0x0. The CPU start fetching instructions from 0xffff0 which is in the middle of NOR. The SRAM is always assumed to be good and used as a scratch space during boot procedure. System configuration information is stored in NOR Flash so no battery backup is provided to the SRAM.
>
> The bootloader code in NOR switches the processor into flat protected mode, enables the DRAM controller and maps the DRAM to 1GB, maps the rest of the NOR to 1MB and jumps to it.
>
> This second stage bootloader copies the third stage bootloader into DRAM and a few instructions into SRAM. Then it jumps into the SRAM remapping DRAM to address 0, and jumps to the third stage bootloader located in DRAM. The SRAM address range cannot be mapped over or moved.
>
> The third stage bootloader initializes the SATA controller and start to query bootable devices in this order: SATA hard drive, SD cards attached on SPI bus, USB Mass Storage devices and network booting.

Comment: That looks to be well beyond any school project.

Comment: How much time does your school allot for this?  Is this a 3-semester diploma thesis project?

Comment: The proposal is way too much and it does not read like an embedded processor -- MMU, ISA bus, SATA interface...

Comment: Seconadry MMU: I need this to remap memory. The NOR Flash have to be at 0x8000 during boot and after boot it should go to 3GB. ISA bus: this is what 80486 talks and it is simple enough to extend into 32 bits. There is no way I can deal with PCI. SATA controller: Optional but useful. The NOR do have 256MB and you can live without it by booting to SD card.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of information about motherboard design in the i80486DX databooks and in the databooks for the supporting chipset(s), these of course written from the point of view, that the 80486, being a PC processor, was intended by the manufacturer to be mainly connected to a chipset of the same manufacturer.

That said, apart from historical interests, it seems difficult to justify the time and energy that would have to be put into such a complex design around an outdated, obsolete and difficult-to-find processor. i80486 is non-RoHS and quite difficult to purchase these days. Instead of the 80486, a much higher performance at a small fraction of the price and design effort would be possible with a mobile applications processor, such as any version of ARM Cortex A. Look at the Raspberry Pi, for example, which runs at 700 MHz and can be purchased for something like $35.

Comment: Instead of ARM, if someone wants an 80x86 compatible microcontroller they can get the [Intel Edison](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13024) with 1 GB RAM, Wi-Fi, UART, SPI, I2C, USB etc etc, way more powerful than any 80486.

Comment: @tcrosley, hey, that looks like fun. Too bad there's no default display on that thing. I can see that Microsoft guys have ported some version of embedded Windows on that thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrRMomesBKM but it would be even more great if I could have an actual keyboard, monitor and mouse hooked up to it 8)

Comment: There is a Linux distro available, so I imagine people are hooking up a keyboard and mouse using a hub attached to the USB.  You can get an Edison in an [Arduino compatible board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13097) so that lets you add an LCD shield.  But it's really not designed for that, really is intended for standalone embedded applications.